# How to scale a plot in mathematica

Tags: plotting

```
a = Sin[2*x];
b = N[Subdivide[0, \[Pi], 99]];
c = Table[a /. x -> b[[i]], {i, 1, Length[b]}];
data = Transpose[{b, c}];
p1 = Plot[a, {x, 0, \[Pi]}];
p2 = ListPlot[data];
Show[p1, p2, AxesStyle -> Black, 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[beam length], HoldForm[normalizd amplitude]}, 
 PlotLabel -> None, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20, GrayLevel[0]}]
```

I have a small piece of code, I am getting a plot but it is not a normalized one, how to scale the plot so that I can visualize the end result with x varies from  0 to 1 and y varies from -1 to 1.

Comment: Us this `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}`

Answer (score 3):

You need `DataRange`:

```
domain = {0, Pi};
points = 100;
x = Array[# &, points, domain];
y = Sin[2 x];
ListPlot[y, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = Function[x, Sin[2*Pi*x]]
p12 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 99,
  AxesLabel -> {"beam length", "normalized amplitude"}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```